# query to the same model with different orderBy

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get posts with different orderBy condition:

```
$most_visited_posts = Post::where('status',1)->orderBy('visit','desc')->get();
$most_commented_posts = Post::where('status',1)->orderBy('comment_count','desc')->get();
```

is there any way to combine these queries into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can pass it as an array:

```
$data = Post::where('status',1)->orderBy(['comment_count'=>'desc', 'visit'=>'desc'])->get();
```

hope it will help you!

Comment: thanks for your response, your answer in somehow correct but the question is how to then separate them and put them in different variables

Comment: you cant! 

if you want them to be seprate you should use seperate queries as you wrote in the question